# Delete items in a dictionary with values that don't equal the highest value in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Essentially I want to delete every key in a dictionary if its value doesn't equal the highest value.

Let's say this is the dictionary:

```
myDict = {"Bob": 1, "Bill": 5, "Barry": 4, "Steve": 5}
```

I'm able to sort it by value using this:

```
myDict = sorted(myDict, key=myDict.get, reverse=True)
```

Now I want to remove any key in the dictionary that doesn't equal the highest value (in this case '5'). To end up with this:

```
myDict = {"Bill": 5, "Steve": 5}
```

I've tried using this for loop:

```
for item, v in myDict:
    if v < myDict[0]:
        del myDict[v]
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This is a) my first time posting here, and b) I've only been learning Python for a few months so I'm sorry if I've made any stupid mistakes.

Comment: To get the highest value, you don't need to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never alter the object you're iterating over, that usually yields unexpected results (internal pointers get shifted and you miss elements in your iteration and such). You best gather the keys you want to delete and then remove the keys in a separate iteration:

```
keys = [k for k in myDict.keys() if myDict[k] == max(myDict.values())];
for k in keys: del myDict[k];
```

It might be best to put the `max` expression in a variable too so it doesn't get evaluated multiple times. Not sure if Python's able to optimize that for you (probably not).

Answer (score 1):

`for item, v in myDict`  just give you `keys` `mydict`, and you are collecting that key in `item, v` that's why,

use `myDict.items()` or `myDict.iteritems()`.

```
for item, v in myDict.iteritems():
    if v < myDict[0]:
        del myDict[v]
```

To get Highest value of `myDict`

`max(myDict.values())`

To `delete` keys from `Dict` never change the iterator you are iterating on, it will give you `RuntimeError`. So copy it in another variable and change previous one as `Anand S Kumar` suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary:

```
newDict = {k: v for k,v in myDict.items() if v == max(myDict.values())}
```

The output for `newDict`:

```
{'Steve': 5, 'Bill': 5}
```